# How can I tell to SonarQube not to check certain code lines?

Tags: sonarqube

I wanted to know if I can tell to SonarQube don`t to check "catch(){}" code lines in duplication?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus)? Why do you think that ignoring "catch() {}" (without any code inside the catch block) is a good thing?

Comment: It's empty because i want to ignore everything inside catch(){}.